# React Select OnChange by Index

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Can anyone help me im stuck at React Select Onchange by Index

```
   <Select
       name="taskTitle"
       value={resultTitle[idx]}
       onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}
       options={optionResultTask}
   />
```

---

```
handleChange = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log(idx);
    const task_results = [...this.state.task_results];
    task_results[idx] = {
      [name]: value
    };
    this.setState({
      task_results
    });
  };
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lpkx235yzq)

My OnChange Function got error
Thanks.

Comment: change `const { name, value } = e.target;` **=>** `const { name, value } = e;` this will work I tried it in Codesandbox  but option value will not be updated because you are not updating `resultTitle`. `const { name, value } ` this should be `const { label, value } `

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it.

My select (rendered inside of a UI that can have N number of children, built by mapping over it):

```
{data.items.map((item, index) => 
  <Select
    options={dogFoodOptions}
    isMulti={false}
    name="dogfood"
    id="dogfood"
    value={item.value}
    onChange={handleDogFoodChange(index)}
    />
}
```

The function:

```
const handleDogFoodChange = index => (option) => {
    console.log(`index: ${index}, value: ${JSON.stringify(option)}`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React Select `onChange` handler is called with the selected option as parameter (not an event), so change your code to something like this :

```
handleChange = idx => selected => {
    console.log(idx, selected);
    const { label, value } = selected;
    // rest of your code
};
```